# AppleScript move Outlook email to folder

Tags: outlook, applescript

I have been using the below script for several months with no issue, however recently it seems unable to find any new folders I add to Outlook, still works fine for those that were already there.

The script worked fine with n tiers without me having to explicitly define subfolders.

```
  on run {}
    tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
        activate
        set messageAccount to first exchange account
        set aMessage to selection
        set messageSender to sender of aMessage
        set senderName to name of messageSender

        try
            move aMessage to folder senderName
        on error
            display dialog senderName & " not found."
        end try

    end tell
end run
```